# Showing that a subgroup is the largest normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$ be a subgroup. Let $X=G/H$ be the left coset space. For $g\in G$, define $\tilde{g}:G/H \to G/H$ by $\tilde{g}(xH)=gxH$ for $x\in G$.

Show that $\ker(\sim)$ is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.

**My solution:**

It's routine to show that $\ker(\sim)=\{g\in H:gx=xg\:\:\forall x\in G\}$. Now assume to the contrary that there is a normal subgroup $A\leq G$ contained in $H$ that properly contains $\ker(\sim)$. Take an $a\in A$ such that there is an $x\in G$ such that $ax\not= xa$. So, $\tilde{a}(xH)=axH\not=xH$. On the other hand, $\tilde{a}(aH\cdot xH)=aaxH$ and $\tilde{a}(aH\cdot xH)=\tilde{a}(aH)\cdot\tilde{a}(xH)=aaH\cdot axH$, which means that $aaxH=aaaxH$ and $xH=axH$. Contradiction.

Is there any mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: Is $H$ normal? What is $\sim$?

Comment: $H$ needs not be normal

Comment: No $H$ is just a subgroup. $\sim:G\to Sym(X)$ takes $g$ to $\tilde{g}$.

Comment: Why don't you give an implicit form of $Ker(~)$?

Comment: @SnowAngel6147 Like $Z(H)$?

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{align*} \ker(~) &=\left \{ g \in H \mid gxH=xH, \forall x\in G \right \}\\ &= \left \{ g \in G\mid (x^{-1}gx)H=H,\forall x\in G \right \} \\ &= \left \{ g \in G\mid x^{-1}gx \in H,\forall x\in G \right \}\\ &= \left \{ g \in G\mid g \in xHx^{-1},\forall x\in G \right \}\\ &= \bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1} \end{align*}$

And note that $\ker()$ is a normal subgoup of $G$, and $\ker() \leq  H$.

If $A$ is any normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, then we have :$A=xAx^{-1} \leq xHx^{-1}, \forall x\in G$.

So, $A\leq \bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}=\ker()  $ which implies what you claimed.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you, yours is much better. Could you point out my mistakes?